# NextJS pages/index.ts overriden by pages/[catchAll].tsx route only in Production

Tags: next.js, next-router

I'm trying to achieve dynamic routing like this:

Example route: **pages/[...slug].tsx**

- example.com/first-page
- example.com/second-page
- example.com/any-page

The problem is that **example.com/** is caught by **pages/[...slug].tsx**.
And at the same time I need to have my **example.com/** accessed through **pages/index.tsx**, as well as **pages/404.tsx** and any other route that is defined separately. For some reason, routes defined in **pages/posts/index.tsx** work fine, and are not falling under the slug dynamic routing, but 404 doesn't.

Right now the **example.com/** gives "Too many redirects" because my slug is unable to properly handle this empty route, so it redirects to **/** or **/404** just to repeat the cycle.

#### What I've tried

- Trying to handle custom routes manually (with no luck, as they still lead to the same route)
- Some deprecated next config parameters (concurrentFeatures)
- Refactoring / to be a separate named page and rendering dynamically either slug or index

I am using T3 stack

---

***EDIT:**

I should also mention that this problem is only happening on my server, running Docker container with Prisma MySQL database and NextJS.
Locally, even with production build and **yarn start**, everything works as expected and routes are caught properly

---

***EDIT 2:**

Here is a little more easy to grasp context:
Page structure:

```
-/pages
    index.tsx
    [slug].tsx
    somepage.tsx
    -/login
        index.tsx
```

Scenario:

**LOCAL**
Local yarn build -> yarn start

1. go to localhost:3000/ -> ✔
2. go to localhost:3000/login -> ✔
3. Go to localhost:3000/somepage -> ✔
4. Go to localhost:3000/slugpage -> ✔

**SERVER**

Server is on DigitalOcean running Docker, CloudFlare also connected to domain.

Builds fine, pushes Prisma, next start -> No errors

1. **go to production.com/ -> 404 (Caught by /pages/[slug].tsx) <-- PROBLEM**
2. go to production.com/login -> ✔ (Doesn't get caught by same slug)
3. go to production.com/somepage -> ✔
4. go to production.com/slugpage -> ✔

Now, why would local production build & serve act differently than on the server?